# How to start new browser window in cpecified location whith cpecified size

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I create a new instance and trying to resize new instance of browser like this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref tagWINDOWINFO pwi);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct tagRECT
    {
        /// LONG->int
        public int left;

        /// LONG->int
        public int top;

        /// LONG->int
        public int right;

        /// LONG->int
        public int bottom;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct tagWINDOWINFO
    {
        /// DWORD->unsigned int
        public uint cbSize;

        /// RECT->tagRECT
        public tagRECT rcWindow;

        /// RECT->tagRECT
        public tagRECT rcClient;

        /// DWORD->unsigned int
        public uint dwStyle;

        /// DWORD->unsigned int
        public uint dwExStyle;

        /// DWORD->unsigned int
        public uint dwWindowStatus;

        /// UINT->unsigned int
        public uint cxWindowBorders;

        /// UINT->unsigned int
        public uint cyWindowBorders;

        /// ATOM->WORD->unsigned short
        public ushort atomWindowType;

        /// WORD->unsigned short
        public ushort wCreatorVersion;
    }


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (System.Diagnostics.Process browserProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            browserProc.StartInfo.FileName = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
            browserProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            int i= browserProc.Id;
            tagWINDOWINFO info = new tagWINDOWINFO();
            info.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);

            browserProc.Start();

            GetWindowInfo(browserProc.MainWindowHandle, ref info);

            browserProc.WaitForInputIdle();
            string str = browserProc.MainWindowTitle;
            MoveWindow(browserProc.MainWindowHandle, 100, 100, 100, 100, true);
            UpdateWindow(browserProc.MainWindowHandle);

        }
    }
```

But I get an "No process is associated with this object". Could anyone help?
Or mb other ideas how to run new browser window whith specified size and location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I fiend a solution! But, it works (in my system, at least) only whith IE...

We need to wait, until the Windows associate a window with process. Like this:

```
while (browserProc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)//пока винда не ассоциировала окно с процессом
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);// ждём 50 мс
                browserProc.Refresh();// обновялем процесс
            }
```

And then we can obtain MainWindowHandle.